# B+ Tree Insertion - Theoretical Question

Tags: database, indexing, theory, b-tree

I have been trying to know how B+ Tree works and been trying to solve the examples.

In one such document listed [here](http://www.ceng.metu.edu.tr/~karagoz/ceng302/302-B+tree-ind-hash.pdf), in the Example 1 given on page 8. It describes a B+ tree construction, where *'n'* number of search key values per node - is given as 4.

Everything goes according to the rules till the third step, but suddenly in the 4th step you see the root node being split, and other splits coming up. I understood why the node 17,19,21 is split(this is apparently not shown in the text). But I'm surprised why the root is split up. Can anyone clarify this to me or suggest a better example which is quite complicated but with a more distinctive and step-by-step approach.

Comment: Suggested reading: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~hector/cs245/Notes04.ppt (from slide 91 onwards; I learned it myself using these slides, but when I now look at these, they are not very explanatory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how B-Trees work: Leaf nodes are filled and on overflow they Split, sending 1 keyvalue up. The node above could then also split, all the way up to the root.

The example is a little weak, normally all nodes except the root are at least half-full. But half of 3 is 1, so this is not too obvious.

Comment: it was given as ciel(n-1/2). That will be 2? Can you cite any better resource?

Comment: Yes you are right, the split at non-leaf node will be ceil(n/2)-1 and at lead node it is ciel(n-1/2)

Comment: Am sorry for asking the question, as it is pretty easy to solve. I did not read the rules with enough attention. Thank you once again I realized were I went wrong. The root is split because, of the split coming from the child node (17,19,21) awaiting an entry of 20, when this split occurs a new node with 20 as parent originates, but according to the b-tree rule all leaf nodes have to be at the same height. So you split the root node to accomodate an extra level created by the key 20. Thank you once again.